# Is it possible to mklink a directory to different target for different users? (windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-7, mklink

Is it possible to mklink a directory to different target for different users? (windows 7)
for example, c:\abc , userA check c:\abc will see his files actually mklink to other place, say, %USERPROFILE%\abc, while userB check c:\abc will see his own files.
This is because there is a software and I don't have its source code, and I want it to operate 2 instances concurrently with different users, but it uses the same directory c:\abc as temp files.
Or not using mklink...any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`mklink` cannot use environment variables, so the answer is "no, that's not possible".

PS: I reviewed "subst", mountpoints and "net use", but none of them will suit your need. In fact, I'm unaware of any technique that will. Sorry :-(